# add html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add rows to a table on user input/select. Cannot use jQuery, Mootools 1.3.2 is ok.

I have a `<select id="copy_selected" class="select" onchange="add_copy()" >` field that `onchange` runs a function add_copy.

The html is ([Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKDP/1/))

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="side" id="copy_settings_desc">Wich to copy?</td>
    <td>
        <select id="copy_selected" class="select" onchange="add_copy()">
            <option value="0">test 1</option>
            <option value="1">test 2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="copy_expandable"></tr>
```

and the not working script is:

```
var copy_counter = 0;

function add_copy() {
copy_counter = copy_counter + 1;
var addition_text = document.getElementById('copy_selected').options[document.getElementById('copy_selected').selectedIndex].text;
var addition_id = document.getElementById("copy_selected").value;
new_addition = '<td></td>' + '<td></td>' + '</tr><tr>' + 
    '<td class="side">' + document.getElementById("copy_settings_desc").innerHTML + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + addition_text + 
    '<input type="hidden" name="copy_to[copy_counter]" value=' + addition_id + '>' +
    '</td>';
document.getElementById("copy_expandable").innerHTML = document.getElementById("copy_expandable").innerHTML + new_addition;
}
```

I understand writing html with script is not good practice. (and in this case not even working)

What would be a good way to do this? Thank you.

**EDIT**: fixed concatenating (thanks for pointing out that). Can you notice the `<tr></tr>` line are ignored on each new selection? why?

Comment: Well, you're not concatenating properly... Try linting your code or debugging with console, you should see an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have syntax errors in defining HTML string(they are not well concatenated), [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKDP/1/) is your Fiddle updated and working!

Strings in JS cannot be on multiple lines, you have to use `+` operator to concat them, or you can even use `\` to define multiple line strings, this is an example:

```
var myString = 'this is\
                a string\
                on multiple line!';
```

**EDIT**: as you requested, with [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yKDP/6/) your code works. I changed the id of the table so you can append HTML just before its end with `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` [function(MDN Reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML). The style of your code changed a bit, but I think that this is what you want, so check it out!

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem. Yes, you are right, my JS skills are limited. Your Fiddle is not working as I expect, can you notice the `<tr></tr>` line are ignored on each new selection? why?

Comment: Updated! Check it out now

Comment: Great! thank you for taking time to check it an pointing out concatenation problems.

Comment: There are better ways to manipulate DOM(see below), but I didn't want to change your code too much(imo, it is right for you to learn step by step, also I don't think it's good to have someone doing homeworks for you ;) )

Answer (score 2):

When you want to create elements, it is a good practice never to append HTML code itself. Rather, you should **use the JavaScript functions** and **let it manipulate the DOM for you**.

In your specific case, the creation of new rows and cells can be achieved through a combination of [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement), [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) [`table.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow), [`row.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell), [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) and other functions:

```
var table = document.getElementById('myTable'); // get table
var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length); // insert row at the end

var cellA = row.insertCell(0); // create cell
var textA = document.createTextNode('<p>text</p> A'); // <p> will not render as
cellA.appendChild(textA);                             // HTML, but as if it were
                                                      // escaped text like &gt;
var cellB = row.insertCell(1);
var textB = document.createTextNode('text for column B');
cellB.appendChild(textB);

var myInput = document.createElement("input"); // create <input>
myInput.type = "text";                         // set input's attributes
myInput.name = "myInput";
myInput.value = 'my DOM created Input';
cellB.appendChild(myInput);                    // appends <input> to cell
```

It is pretty simple and foolproof. [**Check out a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rZWm3/) of your code using this.

Comment: Just saw your comment after accepting answer. Good idea also. +1 from me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changed your script, now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5yKDP/2/ 
Try to be more careful when concatenating strings. And look in your console, to know, if there are any errors in your script.
If you are looking for multiline strings in your scripts, consider writing such code:

```
var multiline = "i\
                 have two lines"
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem. Yes, you are right, my JS skills are limited. Console just said "Illegal token" and I did not know why :) Your Fiddle is not working as I expect, can you notice the <tr></tr> line are ignored on each new selection? why?